# How to trigger a cell change from within a component to update the grid data? (AG Grid - React)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I have a dropdown component within an Ag Grid. But when I change the value, the client-side data object doesn't change.

I'm triggering a function within the component when the dropdown is changed - but how can I tell the "parent" AG Grid to update it's data for that cell? (AG Grid automatically updates it's data when you're just changing text directly in a cell, not using a custom component.)

It seems to have something to do with using getValue(), but I can't seem to find the proper call in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a Cell Renderer or Cell Editor to build the dropdown component?

If using a Custom Cell Editor, you must implement the `getValue` method otherwise the grid will not insert the new value into the row after editing is done.

See this implemented here:

```
const CustomCellEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('United States');
  const values = ['United States', 'Russia', 'Canada'];

  /* Component Editor Lifecycle methods */
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      getValue() {
        return selectedValue;
      },
    };
  });

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedValue} onChange={onChangeHandler}>
        {values.map((item) => (
          <option>{item}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/q4jdHytKIxzCcdpi)

[Documentation on Custom Cell Editors](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-editor/)

Comment: I've tried this, but when it's in a separate component, it doesn't seem to do anything. (It works other than what I'm trying to get it to do - it doesn't trigger an update to the grid data - such as an "onCellValueChanged".

Comment: I wasn't able to run your codesandbox as there were a few errors, I've instead updated the plunkr to have the custom cell editor as a separate React Component. SInce you are using functional components, you have to use  forwardRef / useImperativeHandler so that getValue is called.

Comment: So I guess my problem was that I was using a cellRender, instead of a cellEditorFramework. (which was your first question) When I change it to like you have it in the plunkr, then it triggers the change in the grid. But is there a way to somehow combine the functionality of cellRender and cellEditor? Because I want it rendering the dropdown all the time - not only when you go to edit the cell. And then when a change is made, to update the grid.

Comment: I think this might be what I want... but I'm too new to React and AG Grid to know. https://blog.ag-grid.com/take-full-control-of-editing-in-ag-grid/

Comment: Since you want to have a dropdown component rendering in the cell all the time, I would implement this using a Custom Cell Renderer and update the row data using approaches mentioned here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update/

The blog post you've referenced is also similar to what you are looking for